Answers on community wiki questions are not CW?
Whenever a question is made community wiki after the fact, it seems like all the associated answers don't also get concerted.  Here's an example:
Video lectures and presentations on quantitative finance

This is by-design.  Answers posted after a question is manually converted to community wiki will automatically be made community wiki.  However, answers posted before a question is manually converted to community wiki are not switched over.

This seems like not the best behavior when these questions clearly should have been CW to begin with?

We have provided some additional guidance at the blog:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/
TL;DR version

Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly, and only in very specific circumstances.  

